# VMWare Server and RDP stops responding after turning on any VM on the VM Server

Tags: rdp, vmware-server

I have Windows Server 2008 installed on my physical server. On top of that I have VMWare Server 2 installed.

In the VMWare Server, I have 4 Virtual Machines. Every time I turn on one of the VM, I can not connect to my Server 2008 or connect to my VM Server Web Interface at https://IP:8333

I'm really not sure whats going on here and if someone can help out it would be really great.

Thanks.